# Have file be part of multiple targets by default in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have a project with two targets.  As I add new files to the project, by default only one target is selected (see screenshot).  Can I default to having both targets selected?

[image: Last screen in add file wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a library that is built from the shared source files. This would be a third target which could be made a dependency of your present pair of targets.

Comment: Accepted as the answer, unless someone comes up with a better answer.